# Cocos2d-x Object Pooling

Tags: cocos2d-x, cocos2d-x-3.0, object-pooling

I created object pool as the following.

```
void Arrow::CreatePools( cocos2d::Layer *layer )
{
    Sprite * sprite;
    int i;

    //--CREATE ENEMY OBJECT POOL--//
    enemyPool = new Vector<Sprite*>(MAX_ENEMY_NUMBER);
    enemyIndex = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < MAX_ENEMY_NUMBER; i++) {
        sprite = Sprite::create("Enemy.png");
        sprite->setVisible(false);
        layer->addChild(sprite);
        enemyPool->pushBack(sprite);
    }
```

When I try to pull object from pool, cocos gives this error; `{return static_cast<size_type>(this->__end_ - this->__begin_);}`

My object pulling method as following.

```
auto enemy = enemyPool->at(enemyIndex);
            enemyIndex++;
            if (enemyIndex == enemyPool->size())
                enemyIndex = 0;
            enemy->stopAllActions();
            enemy->setPosition(myStartPoint);
            enemy->runAction(myAction);
            enemy->setVisible(true);
```

Comment: Which statement is causing the exception?

Comment: CreatePools method is working, but I cant pull object from pool. When I call create enemy method program crashes and cocos library shows this {return static_cast<size_type>(this->__end_ - this->__begin_);}

Answer (score 0):

> for (i = 0; i < MAX_ARROW_NUMBER; i++)

does MAX_ARROW_NUMBER should be MAX_ENEMY_NUMBER ?

because enemyPool is created with size of MAX_ENEMY_NUMBER in

> enemyPool = new Vector(MAX_ENEMY_NUMBER);